# Treat Many Whitespace Characters As a Single Delimiter

Tags: c#, parsing

When the method `String.Split(null)` encounters many whitespace characters in a row it treats each whitespace character as a delimiter.

So for the following string `a b c   d` the result is:

```
{"a", "b", "c", , , "d"}   // for string[] res = "a b c   d".Split(null);
```

Is it possible to to make `String.Split(null)` treat many whitespace characters as a single delimiter? Is there a different method that can do this?

Ie, is there a method that will achieve this result:

```
{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
```

Before I go and reinvent the wheel (write my own method to convert multiple whitespace characters to a single char then use `String.Split(null)`) I want to check that there isn't an existing method that will do this for me.

Comment: At first split might seems like an obvious choice to parse something because it is so simple, but its not meant for parsing. Only use split if you're doing hacky stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) to the `Split` method. There is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) that takes in this enum

```
yourString.Split(null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx). This will remove the extra entries in the list. To keep the default (i.e. whitespace) splitting you can continue to pass `null` as the first argument, e.g:

```
"a b c   d".Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```